# CURLOPT_USERPWD seems to be ignored

Tags: libcurl, basic-authentication

Usinglibcurl version: 7.19.7

[Sorry for the verbosity of this message]

I am having problems getting simple Basic
authentication to work with libcurl.
I have a server setup to provide a password
protected piece of data: url is in the code.

I took the simple.c libcurl example
and modified it to set CURLOPT_USERPWD
(code below). When I run it, I get the
curl verbose output below [html styles elided].

Notes:

1. if I paste the url into a browser, it will
      ask for the user and password and if supplied
      it returns the data correctly. I assume this
      means that the server's claim of being
      unauthorized is bogus (correct?).

   If I put the "username:passwd@" into the url, I appear
      to get the same result.

Anyone see the problem?

=Dennis Heimbigner
Unidata

### Curl verbose Output

```
* About to connect() to utmea.enea.it port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 192.107.77.41... * connected
* Connected to utmea.enea.it (192.107.77.41) port 8080 (#0)
> > GET /thredds/dodsC/UNIDATA_passwd/head_out.nc.dds HTTP/1.1
Host: utmea.enea.it:8080
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Last-Modified: 
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BEC21BBB6DD954B7BD60F1BED1414A8E; Path=/thredds/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://utmea.enea.it:8080/thredds/restrictedAccess/accediUNIDATA
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 18:49:00 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host utmea.enea.it left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://utmea.enea.it:8080/thredds/restrictedAccess/accediUNIDATA'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host utmea.enea.it
* Connected to utmea.enea.it (192.107.77.41) port 8080 (#0)
> > GET /thredds/restrictedAccess/accediUNIDATA HTTP/1.1
Host: utmea.enea.it:8080
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="THREDDS Data Server"
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 951
< Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 18:49:00 GMT
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host utmea.enea.it left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://utmea.enea.it:8080/thredds/restrictedAccess/accediUNIDATA'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host utmea.enea.it
* Connected to utmea.enea.it (192.107.77.41) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'ticket'
> > GET /thredds/restrictedAccess/accediUNIDATA HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dGlja2V0OnRpY2tldDE=
Host: utmea.enea.it:8080
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E0E3AC390A39C786C3CFD139F601D8B8; Path=/thredds/; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1027
< Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 18:49:00 GMT
< 
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 - Error report</title>
<style>...</style>
</head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - Not authorized to access this dataset.</h1>
... not authorized to access this dataset.</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p>...<h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.35</h3></body></ht* Connection #0 to host utmea.enea.it left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

### Modified simple.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://utmea.enea.it:8080/thredds/dodsC/UNIDATA_passwd/head_out.nc.dds");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ticket:ticket1");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I paste the url into a browser [...] it returns the data correctly. I assume this means that the server's claim of being unauthorized is bogus (correct?).

No: this is because the browser supports cookies (which is what this web service expects here).

Tell libcurl [to enable cookies for your session](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCOOKIEJAR):

```
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
...
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your paste we see how curl sends

> Authorization: Basic dGlja2V0OnRpY2tldDE=

... to the server which we can base64 decode and see that you made it send "ticket:ticket1" as user and password using Basic auth. And the server rejects that with a 401.

I don't see how this is curl's fault...

Comment: Fault is not the issue; the issue is what